# How to remove a frame from the total number of frames?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, overlays

I'm using Warsaw as outer theme. I use some images in different slides to create an effect of 'image in evolution' but the problem is that I don't want that the number of slides increase with every frame used to create the effect. How can I do to remove a frame from the total number of frames. I've been reading about 'overlay' and tikspicture but I just receive errors in compilation. I use Winedt v5.4. Thanks in advance to everybody.

P.S. The images stay always in the same position.

Here is the link to the pdf showing the effect I want:
[Latex effect wanted PDF](http://www.mediafire.com/?491uddw4ca63b4y)

I'd like to have all the images from slide number 3 until slide number 20 in the same frame to avoid count them and increase the total number of frames. It looks that I've got the effect wanted using `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` but I can't use `\caption` and have a 'footprint' for the images. And while the images are being uncovered the footline where are found the total number of frames disappears. The error for the `\caption` says: \caption outside float.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{albatross}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title[This is the title      \hspace{18mm}                  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{\small{\texttt{Name a little bit long}}}
\author{This is author}
\institute[Name]{SCHOOL}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Content}
    \scriptsize{ \tableofcontents[]}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \setbeamercovered{invisible}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(first image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/1.png}\caption{We are young}

}; \pause

 \node(2 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/2.png}\caption{We are young}
}; \pause

\node(3 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/3.png}\caption{We are young}
};\pause

\node(4 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/4.png}\caption{We are young}
};\pause

\node(5 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/5.png}\caption{We are young}
};\pause

\node(6 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/6.png}
};\pause

\node(7 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/7.png}
};\pause

\node(8 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/8.png}
};\pause

\node(9 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/9.png}
};\pause

\node(10 image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/10.png}
};\pause

\node(11image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/11.png}
};\pause

\node(12image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/12.png}
};\pause

\node(13image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/13.png}
    };\pause

\node(14image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/14.png}
};\pause

\node(15image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/15.png}
};\pause

\node(16image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/16.png}
};\pause

\node(17image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/18.png}
};\pause

\node(18image){
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{./IMAGENES/19.png}
};\pause
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So, how can I add the number of frames using `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` and write a footline for the images?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The poor man's solution is to manually decrement the page numbers. Obviously not the most elegant...

Comment: I do not know if this solves your issue but it may be useful to know that the macro `\insertpagenumber` prints the number of the page in the pdf (so generating the undesired counting in your case) but `\insertframenumber` insert the number of the current `\frame` which will not increase when just stepping through an animation.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to tell you that I found a solution. The effect I tried to show is working perfectly using the command `\only` then use `\begin{figure}`, `\centering` and only so I could use `\caption`. The page of the frame doesn't change while showing the different images. Thanks a lot to everyone who answered and suggested options. A last question would be, how can I finish this answer?